# django database inserts not getting picked up

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, transactions

We have a little bit of a complicated setup:

In our normal code, we connect manually to a mysql db. We're doing this because I guess the connections django normally uses are not threadsafe? So we let django make the connection, extract the information from it, and then use a mysqldb connection to do the actual querying.

Our code is largely an update process, so we have autocommit turned off to save time.

For ease of creating test data, I created django models that represent the tables, and use them to create rows to test on. So I have functions like:

```
def make_thing(**overrides):
    fields = deepcopy(DEFAULT_THING)
    fields.update(overrides)
    s = Thing(**fields)
    s.save()
    transaction.commit(using='ourdb')
    reset_queries()
    return s
```

However, it doesn't seem to actually be committing! After I make an object, I later have code that executes raw sql against the mysqldb connection:

```
def get_information(self, value):
    print self.api.rawSql("select count(*) from thing")[0][0]
    query = 'select info from thing where column = %s' % value
    return self.api.rawSql(query)[0][0]
```

This print statement prints 0! Why?

Also, if I turn autocommit off, I get 
`TransactionManagementError: This is forbidden when an 'atomic' block is active.`

when we try to alter the autocommit level later.

EDIT: I also just tried https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/4lzsQAWYwG0, which did not help.

EDIT2: I checked from a shell against the database--the commit *is* working, it's just not getting picked up. I've tried setting the transaction isolation level but it isn't helping. I should add that a function further up from get_information uses this decorator:

```
def single_transaction(fn):
    from django.db import transaction
    from django.db import connection

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        prior_autocommit = transaction.get_autocommit()
        transaction.set_autocommit(False)
        connection.cursor().execute('set transaction isolation level read committed')
        connection.cursor().execute("SELECT @@session.tx_isolation")
        try:
            result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
            transaction.commit()
            return result

        finally:
            transaction.set_autocommit(prior_autocommit)
            django.db.reset_queries()
            gc.collect()

    wrapper.__name__ = fn.__name__
    return wrapper
```

Comment: It has to be Mysql? I know that MySql poorly support transaction. Here is some article: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/transactions/#transactions-in-mysql. If mysql is not required, try to use postgres :)

Comment: Mysql is required. This is production software, we can't just change our database like that.

Comment: Can you create the mysqldb connection after you commit?